# Python Pinpoint differences between two column with unique value

Tags: python, pandas

I apologize for the rough title, but i have the following scenario:

2 dataframe columns with values:

Ball | 1

Ball | 1

Stick | 2

Stick | 3

Basically, how would i be able to run some sort of validation check to say, Ball is fine because it has 1 unique value in column 2, but stick is wrong because it has 2 and 3 which are not the same? I want each unique value in column 1 to only have 1 unique value.

Comment: Some clarification: if there are ever columns with the same name, you want to check that for each row, those columns have the same value? Or they each have only one value, which is the same (but not multiple values on different rows)?

Comment: sorry, so i would just be looking at these two columns regardless of name. i want them to have the same values or not other values in other rows like stick does.

Comment: Do you have two columns name `Ball` and two named `Stick` and you want them to be the same as each other? Or do you have one column named `Ball` and one named `Stick` and each column should only contain a single value?

Comment: 2nd half. ball is fine in above exmaple because it only has 1 value associated with it in column 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.duplicated(subset='Ball')
```

this will return a series of booleans denoting whether the values are duplicates of a prior row

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html

```
   Ball Stick
0   1   2
1   1   3
```

returns

```
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

**EDITED**:

So I think I know where OP is going

If I set up a df with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1','2'],['1','2'],['1','8']], columns=['Ball','Stick'])
```

df returns

```
   Ball Stick
0   1   2
1   1   2
2   1   8
```

then:

```
for row in df:
    print(row)
    print(df.duplicated(subset=row, keep=False))
```

returns:

```
Ball
0    True
1    True
2    True
dtype: bool
Stick
0     True
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

So any column with a False in it will be 'Bad'

Comment: For me, this returns `ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)` if you have two columns with the same name as the OP does. Though I'm not sure I understand the OP's setup.

Comment: I thought the column names were 'Ball' and 'Stick'?

Comment: Sorry, I think you're right. I originally thought the OP had two columns named Ball (with values 1 and 1) and two named Stick (with values 2 and 3). The diagram in the question wasn't clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.groupby()` with `.nunique()`:

```
df.groupby('column_1_name')['column_2_name'].nunique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read CSV file without column name and can get values as follows

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',header=None)
print(df.groupby(0)[1].nunique()==1)
```

Result:

```
Ball      True
Stick    False
```